# Meaning of notation concerning parameter range

Tags: notation

I have recently seen in the context of so called doubly non-linear pde a notation concerning a parameter range where the following term $\hat{p}<\frac{n(p-1)}{(n-p)_+}$ appeared. Here $p,\hat{p}$ denote the exponents which lead to non-linearity but are not of further interest for my question and $(\cdot)_+$ denotes the positive part of some scalar quantity in $\mathbb{R}$.
So in the case $p<n$, where $n$ as usual denotes the space dimension, the term above is well defined. But what about the case $p\geq n$? Is this understood in the sense that $\hat{p}<\frac{n(p-1)}{0} := \infty$ and thus no upper bound on $\hat{p}$ is required or is it meant that the case $p\geq n$ simply is not allowed in this context?

Thanks in adcance!